# How to get 2nd occurance of a substing in a string VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell formula like 
[image]

I want to replace specific # with `check#` with an integer I have tried this

```
result = Replace(Cell.formula, "#", i)
  Cell.formula = result
```

but it also changes the # with `#00D700`
so I want to get the # which comes after 2nd`*` sign in cell formula.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Replace(Cell.formula, "check#", "check" & i)`